# Generating cacheable data exactly once when needed and blocking otherwise?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, concurrency, t4

I'm making a cool (imo) T4 template which will make caching a lot easier. One of the options I have in making this template is to allow for a "load once" type functionality, though I'm not sure how safe it is.

Basically, I want to make it so you can do something like this:

```
var post=MyCache.PostsCache.GetOrLockLoad(id, ()=>LoadPost(id));
```

and basically make it so that when the cache must be loaded, it will place a blocking lock across `PostsCache`. This way, other threads would block until the `LoadPost()` function is done. This makes it so that LoadPost will only be executed once per cache miss. The traditional way of doing this is LoadPost will be executed anytime the cache is empty, possibly multiple times if multiple requests for it come before the cache is loaded the first time.

Is this a reasonable thing to do, or is blocking other threads for something like this dangerous or wasteful? I'm thinking something along the lines that the thread locking overheads are greater than most operations, but maybe not?

Has anyone seen this kind of thing done and is it a good idea or just dangerous?

Also, although it's designed to run on any cache and application type, it's initially being targetted at ASP.Net's built in caching mechanism.

Comment: Yes is well-known pattern supported for instance by .NET Lazy class (although this isn't a cache per se). It's useful when .LoadPost in your sample would consume alot of Resources/returns different results depending on time/mutates data. However, for other cases I tend to avoid it for throughput.

Comment: @FuleSnabel interesting. This is actually the first time I'm seeing the Lazy<T> stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This seems ok, since in theory the requests after the first will only wait about as long as it would have taken for them to load the data themselves anyway.

But it still feels a bit iffy - what if the first loader thread gets held up due to some intermittent issue that may not affect other threads. It feels like it would be safer to let each thread try the load independently.

It's also adding the complexity and overhead of the locking mechanisms. Keep in mind the more locking you do, the more risk you introduce of getting a deadlock condition (in general). Although in your case, as long as there's no funky locking going on in the `LoadPost` method it shouldn't be an issue.

Given the risks, I think you would be better off going with a non-locking option.

After all, for any given thread the wait time is pretty much the same - either the time taken to load, or the time spent waiting for the first thread to load.

I'm always a little uncomfortable when a non-concurrent option is used over a concurrent one, especially if the gain seems marginal.

Comment: Well, I'm going to allow both versions, but I'm wondering if this ambitious load-once thing is even worth implementing. It sounds good, but also very risky. It's also not trivial as to what should be done if ASP.Net's cache decides to not cache the object being stored (which I assume isn't impossible, but not very probable)

Comment: I think it's worth trying out, even if just for the fun if it, as long as you also keep a non-locking option handy in case things get hairy :)